# Проблема с переходом анимации после прыжка

Tags: c#, unity3d, анимация

Возникла проблема с переходом анимации из Jump в Idle. Есть персонаж, когда он прыгает он переходит из анимации Idle в Jump, а вот когда приземляеть из Jump в Idle не переходит. Я использую кнопки Button с компонентом event trigger.
Вот мой код:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Upravlenie : MonoBehaviour {

    public float horizontalSpeed;
    float speedX;
    public float verticalImpulse;
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    bool isGrounded;
    private bool isFacingRight = true;
    bool Fliped = false;

    private Animator animator;

    private CharState State
    {
        get { return (CharState)animator.GetInteger("State"); }
        set { animator.SetInteger("State", (int)value); }
    }

    void Start () {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    private void Flip()
    {
        isFacingRight = !isFacingRight;
        Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
        theScale.x *= -1;
        transform.localScale = theScale;
    }

    public void LeftButtonDown()
    {
        speedX = -horizontalSpeed;
        if (isGrounded) State = CharState.Run;
        if (Fliped == false) 
            Flip(); 
            Fliped = true; 
    }

    public void RightButtonDown()
    {
        speedX = horizontalSpeed;
        if (isGrounded) State = CharState.Run;
        if (Fliped == true) 
            Flip(); 
            Fliped = false; 
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        speedX = 0;
    }

    public void A_Idle()
    {
        State = CharState.Idle;
    }

    public void OnClickJump()
    {
        if (isGrounded)
            rb.AddForce(new Vector2(0, verticalImpulse), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        if (isGrounded) State = CharState.Jump;
    }


    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        transform.Translate(speedX, 0, 0);
    }
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Ground")
            isGrounded = true;
    }
    private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Ground")
            isGrounded = false;
    }
}

public enum CharState
{
    Idle,
    Run,
    Jump
}
```

Прошу помочь.

Comment: А если в `OnCollisionEnter2D` добавить `State = CharState.Idle;` вместе с `isGrounded = true;`  ? ............ Кстати, в `OnClickJump` у тебя два раза написано `if (isGrounded)`. Второй раз излишен.....

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Спасибо помогло